# App crashed when the Fragment that uses MP Android Chart library is executed

Tags: android, android-fragments, mpandroidchart

I'm using a Navigation drawer activity with fragments and I have implemented MP Android Chart library on one of those fragments. But when that fragment is executed, the app crashes. I went through so many threads and tutorial but I can't figure out where the problem is.

I have coded the following lines on respective classes and files.

The Fragment class:

```
package com.example.maleesha5.elektra11;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by kokil on 21/05/2017.
 */


public class Statistics extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics, container, false);

        BarChart chart = (BarChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

        BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.setDescription("My Chart");
        // chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
        chart.invalidate();

        return rootView;
    }

    private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet1.add(v1e1);
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
        BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(30.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet1.add(v1e4);
        BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet1.add(v1e5);
        BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet1.add(v1e6);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v2e1 = new BarEntry(150.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet2.add(v2e1);
        BarEntry v2e2 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet2.add(v2e2);
        BarEntry v2e3 = new BarEntry(120.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet2.add(v2e3);
        BarEntry v2e4 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet2.add(v2e4);
        BarEntry v2e5 = new BarEntry(20.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet2.add(v2e5);
        BarEntry v2e6 = new BarEntry(80.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet2.add(v2e6);

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
        return dataSets;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("JAN");
        xAxis.add("FEB");
        xAxis.add("MAR");
        xAxis.add("APR");
        xAxis.add("MAY");
        xAxis.add("JUN");
        return xAxis;
    }
}
```

The Main Activity class:

```
} else if (id == R.id.nav_stats) {
            setTitle("Statistics");
            Statistics stats= new Statistics();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, stats, "Stats");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'
}
```

The layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does your logcat says at crash?

Comment: Post your errorlog

Comment: Hard to say anything without stacktrace, but put your graph setup in `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView`

Comment: @Akshay  "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart cannot be cast to com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart" appears on the error log.

Comment: @UrošPodkrižnik  "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart cannot be cast to com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart" appears on the error log.

Comment: It is obivous..you are using Barchart in your code and in your xml you are using Linechart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
BarChart chart = (BarChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

with

```
LineChart chart = (LineChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

In your xml you are using class `com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart` while in your fragment you are calling BarChart class

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out through the comments. Accepted your answer as correct.